# htaccess rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite, images

i have a script that uploads images, creates a hash for it, creates 3 directories, and stores the image to

```
imgs/f3s/v5g/234/536_f3sv5g2344270fd093ee8a9bf8de3de32dad.jpg
```

(the “536_” is the user id)

so im trying to turn

```
imgs/f3s/v5g/234/536_f3sv5g2344270fd093ee8a9bf8de3de32dad.jpg
```

into

```
user_pics/536/536_f3sv5g2344270fd093ee8a9bf8de3de32dad.jpg
```

how can i do that? i want that if someone wants to view the photo, they see the new directory in the url, not the one with 3 sub directories.

## EDIT

So jon's method works but but i need to add `RewriteRule .* index.php/$1 [PT,L]` to my htaccess. when i add that, everything stops working how come?

this is what i currently have so far

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$1 [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^user_pics/([^/]+)/[^*]+*(.{3})(.{3})(.{3})(.*).(jpe?g|gif|png)$ /imgs/$2/$3/$4/$1_$2$3$4$5.$6 [L]

Comment: for "108_" you mean, in the url u gave "536_" ? why do you create all those folders to save the imagen?

Comment: sorry fixed :p. and i created them because there will be A LOT (millions) of pictures on this server so they need to be spread evenly

Comment: added edits to this question....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^user_pics/([^/]+)/[^_]+_(.{3})(.{3})(.{3})(.*)\.(jpe?g|gif|png)$ /imgs/$2/$3/$4/$1_$2$3$4$5.$6 [L]
```

Comment: thanks but that didnt work

Comment: nvm it worked but there is a problem... i need to have this rule in my htaccess `RewriteRule .* index.php/$1 [PT,L]` when i take it out it works, but when i put it in it doesnt. why>?

Comment: @flyenig You want to put the redirect rule above any routing rules (e.g. your "route everything to `index.php`" rule).

Comment: ok i put that before the index.php rule and now my whole site gives me a 500 error, what am i doing wrong?